# Rstudio Crashes after I close the shiny app (using "pool" package)

Tags: shiny, crash, odbc, pool, rstudio-server

I basically have an shiny app like [in this example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/pool-basics.html):

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(pool)

# create the connection
pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "shinydemo",
  host = "shiny-demo.csa7qlmguqrf.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
  username = "guest",
  password = "guest"
)
onStop(function() {
  message("closing...")
  pool::poolClose(pool)
})

# === UI ====
ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("ID", "Enter your ID:", "5"),
  tableOutput("tbl"),
  numericInput("nrows", "How many cities to show?", 10),
  plotOutput("popPlot")
)

#==== SERVER ====
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    sql <- "SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = ?id;"
    query <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql, id = input$ID)
    dbGetQuery(pool, query)
  })
  output$popPlot <- renderPlot({
    query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM City LIMIT ",
                    as.integer(input$nrows)[1], ";")
    df <- dbGetQuery(pool, query)
    pop <- df$Population
    names(pop) <- df$Name
    barplot(pop)
  })
}

#=== Run the App====
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And the error has been already asked in [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-crashes-after-i-close-the-shiny-app/7668) years ago, but the answer does not solve the issue on my side. (they suggest to get the latest "later" package, but I did and the error remains).
So the error is that: once I click on the Stop bottom on my RStudio Server Session (to stop the shiny App dashboard that runs fine) it does not stop. Instead, a window pop-out appears saying: *Terminate R* (And no message error appears in the console)
[image: risnotresponding_whenstoptheshinyapp]

I tried for hours to solve this annoyin behaviour (it makes me recall the system environment variables everytime I restart the Rstudio session) and I found a temporal solution: pressing **"Esc"** button on the "Console", to Stop the process, avoiding that "Terminate R" pop-out. Then it really stops and I can rerun again the Shiny app. I want to remark that the "Stop" icon (see circle in red, on the attached picture)does not work properly. The "Esc" works instead.
Anybody knows why is this happening? I will also report it in GitHub "pool" issues. Although I am not completely sure if the issue is from the package.

*I am using R.4.1.0 (also my connection is to Postgress using a odbc driver, but is not displayed in the code. My session is running in RStudio Workbench 2021.092 (Build 382.pro1). I am ussing "pool" v.0.1.6.*

Answer (score 1):

I noticed some instabilities with the pool package too. For me it resolves when properly checking out and returning an object. Have a look what happens when you change your code as follows:

```
output$tbl <- renderTable({
sql <- "SELECT * FROM City WHERE ID = ?id;"
con <- poolCheckout(pool)
on.exit(poolReturn(con)
dbGetQuery(con, sql)
})
```

And:

```
output$popPlot <- renderPlot({
query <- paste0("SELECT * FROM City LIMIT ",
                as.integer(input$nrows)[1], ";")
con <- poolCheckout(pool)
df <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
poolReturn(con)
pop <- df$Population
names(pop) <- df$Name
barplot(pop)
})
```

I showed you two ways of writing the pool return statement, so you can choose whichever is more natural to you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the solution posted on Posit Community: [R crashes Shiny App](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-crashes-when-closing-shiny-app-window-instead-of-clicking-red-stop-button-in-rstudio/131951)

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage()
server <- function(input, output, session) {  
session$onSessionEnded(function() { stopApp() })}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```